# JFrame Keylistener is taking inputs from user

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener

I have added  a `KeyListener` to a `JFrame`

String1: Coding 
Display:_ _ d _ n g

If I press c it should fill the gaps else it should wait while I press another key.

I need to give only 4 chances to user.

I have built this in console but in console I could add scanner inside a loop.

How do I do that in `JFrame` ?

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    JLabel keylabel = new JLabel("Press any key");

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
         int keycode = e.getKeyCode();
         if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_C)
             keylabel.setText("You pressed correct");
         else
             keylabel.setText("You pressed wrong");

    }
```

The above code i used I'm not getting any idea how to repeat that code for all the blanks.

Comment: In UI you are always in the loop. So you can simply create an `int` field in your class and increment it, when user press a key.

Comment: Hi please check the question which i updated just new

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose something like this:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
JLabel keylabel = new JLabel("Press any key");
private int tries = 10;

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
     keylabel.setText("You pressed " + (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_C ? "correct" : "wrong"));
     if (--tries <= 0) {
         keylabel.setText("No tries left");
         textField.setEnabled(false);
     }
}
```

Comment: there are 3 blanks should i repeat the code thrice?

Comment: Use || operator. `if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_C || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_B)` and so on. Alternative you can define a HashSet with allowed characters and check whether this set contains the character entered by the user.